# pattern matching with multiple options in R

Tags: r, loops, stringr

I have a list of filenames all of which come from different providers. The provider names are given inconsistently, for instance "Apple" and "APPL". I am trying to find a way to append the correct name to the file dataframe, if the data has a matching string. For example, if a filename contained "Apple" then the correct name "APPL" would be appended next to it, in the dataframe. Sorry if I haven't included my attempt at it, I just think that would confuse the question as I am a complete beginner. Thanks heaps!

(In reality I have about 1000 filenames, and 30 or so provider names each of which has around 3 possible patterns it could be. Yikes!)

```
stock_tickers <- data.frame("APPL", "MSFT")

financial_reports <- data.frame("financial_report_names" = "AppleFinance.csv", "APPLStock.csv", "financesMICROSOFT.csv", "MSFTstocks.csv", "UberStocks.csv",
                                "report_month" = "202101", "202101", "202102", "202102", "202102")

APPL_matches <- c("APPL", "Apple")
MSFT_matches <- c("MSFT", "Microsoft")


#expected output
# financial_report_names      report month      matching ticker
# "AppleFinance.csv"          202101            APPL
# "APPLStock.csv"             202102            APPL
# "financesMICROSOFT.csv"     202102            MSFT
# "MSFTstocks.csv"            202102            MSFT
# "UberStocks.csv"            202102            N/A
```

Comment: Have you checked the dataframe created by your code? Are you sure they are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a regex pattern which can take all possible combination of patterns of a ticker and use `stringr::str_replace_all` -

```
ptrn <- c(".*(APPL|Apple|APPLE).*" = 'APPL', 
          ".*(MSFT|Microsoft|MICROSOFT).*" = 'MSFT', 
          ".*(Uber).*" = 'UBER')

stringr::str_replace_all(financial_reports$financial_report_names, ptrn)

#[1] "APPL" "APPL" "MSFT" "MSFT" "UBER"
```

You can also generate this pattern dynamically if saved somewhere in dataframe or csv.

**data**

```
financial_reports <- structure(list(financial_report_names = c("AppleFinance.csv", 
"APPLStock.csv", "financesMICROSOFT.csv", "MSFTstocks.csv", "UberStocks.csv"
), report_month = c("202101", "202101", "202102", "202102", "202102"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```